# Find the value of the expression $\frac{AF}{FD}$.

Tags: geometry, triangles

In the given figure $AC=BD=3$ units and $CE=DE=1$ unit.

Find the value of the expression $\frac{AF}{FD}$.

We know that the median divides the area of a triangle in to two equal halves.

Therefore,

AREA $\triangle ECD$ = $\frac{1}{2}$*$\frac{1}{2}$*(AREA $\triangle EAD$)

[image]

Comment: You have been here long enough to know that questions copy-pasted from unnamed sources with no motivation and no sign of any effort are not well-received by some of the regulars here.

Answer (score 1):

Let $r$ be the bisector of $\angle AEB$. By simmetry, $F$ can be defined as $AD\cap r$. So $\frac{AF}{FD}=\frac{AE}{ED}=4$.

Comment: Could you explain why $AF/FD=AE/ED$? Thanks.

Comment: @Sigur: angle bisector theorem